# Minimal number of dependencies to use CodeIgniter's DB class?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, dependencies

I'm trying to use the CodeIgniter DB functionality (as it's `DB(...)` function, defined in `database/DB.php`) as a stand-alone library.

What would be the minimal environment needed to make this run?

So far I've got:

- `APPPATH`, `BASEPATH` and `ENVIRONMENT`
- `config/config.php`
- `core/Common.php`
- `core/Exceptions.php`
- `core/Lang.php`
- `libraries/Log.php`
- all files in `database/*`

But the code still seems to mysteriously die.

Comment: I'm currently working my way back from a full CodeIgniter, rerunning a testsuite after each file deletion. Though I'll probably miss something here (through lack of test coverage), but I'll probably get a reasonable set of dependencies this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the following link helpful.
http://hasin.me/2007/06/13/using-activerecord-library-separately-from-codeigniter/

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help!